# Which font-faces are available in the "font" tag for the Html.fromHtml function?

Tags: android, fonts, font-face

[**Html.fromHtml**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) barely has any documentations about which tags it supports.

It is written that it does support the "font" tag on many websites (like [**here**](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)), but I can't find out which fonts are available when setting "face" attribute within this tag.

Which fonts can I assume that are always available? Which of them are only from specific Android versions? Is there a list of them somewhere?

EDIT: it seems the answer should be in "/system/etc/fonts.xml" file. Here's its content on Android 6.0.1 :

```
<familyset version="22">
    <!-- first font is default -->
    <family name="sans-serif">
        <font weight="100" style="normal">Roboto-Thin.ttf</font>
        <font weight="100" style="italic">Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="normal">Roboto-Light.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="italic">Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">Roboto-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">Roboto-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="normal">Roboto-Medium.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="italic">Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="normal">Roboto-Black.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="italic">Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">Roboto-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- Note that aliases must come after the fonts they reference. -->
    <alias name="sans-serif-thin" to="sans-serif" weight="100" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-light" to="sans-serif" weight="300" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-medium" to="sans-serif" weight="500" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-black" to="sans-serif" weight="900" />
    <alias name="arial" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="helvetica" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="tahoma" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="verdana" to="sans-serif" />

    <family name="sans-serif-condensed">
        <font weight="300" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="sans-serif-condensed-light" to="sans-serif-condensed" weight="300" />

    <family name="serif">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSerif-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSerif-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">NotoSerif-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">NotoSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="times" to="serif" />
    <alias name="times new roman" to="serif" />
    <alias name="palatino" to="serif" />
    <alias name="georgia" to="serif" />
    <alias name="baskerville" to="serif" />
    <alias name="goudy" to="serif" />
    <alias name="fantasy" to="serif" />
    <alias name="ITC Stone Serif" to="serif" />

    <family name="monospace">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">DroidSansMono.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="sans-serif-monospace" to="monospace" />
    <alias name="monaco" to="monospace" />

    <family name="serif-monospace">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">CutiveMono.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="courier" to="serif-monospace" />
    <alias name="courier new" to="serif-monospace" />

    <family name="casual">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">ComingSoon.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family name="cursive">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">DancingScript-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">DancingScript-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family name="sans-serif-smallcaps">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- fallback fonts -->
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabic-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabicUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabicUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansEthiopic-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansHebrew-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThai-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThai-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThaiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThaiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansArmenian-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansArmenian-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGeorgian-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGeorgian-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagari-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagariUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagariUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!-- Gujarati should come after Devanagari -->
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGujaratiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGujaratiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!-- Gurmukhi should come after Devanagari -->
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhi-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhi-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTamil-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTamilUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTamilUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalam-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalam-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalamUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalamUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBengali-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansBengali-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBengaliUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansBengaliUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTelugu-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTelugu-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTeluguUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTeluguUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKannada-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKannada-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKannadaUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKannadaUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOriya-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansOriya-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOriyaUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansOriyaUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansSinhala-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKhmer-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKhmer-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKhmerUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKhmerUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLao-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansLao-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLaoUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansLaoUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmar-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmar-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmarUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmarUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThaana-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThaana-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCham-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansCham-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBalinese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBamum-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBatak-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBuginese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBuhid-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCanadianAboriginal-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCherokee-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCoptic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansHanunoo-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansJavanese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKayahLi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLepcha-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLimbu-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLisu-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMandaic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMeeteiMayek-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansNewTaiLue-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansNKo-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOlChiki-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansRejang-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSaurashtra-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSundanese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSylotiNagri-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSyriacEstrangela-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTagbanwa-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiTham-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTibetan-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTifinagh-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansVai-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSymbols-Regular-Subsetted.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="zh-Hans">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSC-Regular.otf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="zh-Hant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTC-Regular.otf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="ja">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansJP-Regular.otf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="ko">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKR-Regular.otf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NanumGothic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoColorEmoji.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">DroidSansFallback.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="ja">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">MTLmr3m.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!--
        Tai Le and Mongolian are intentionally kept last, to make sure they don't override
        the East Asian punctuation for Chinese.
    -->
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiLe-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMongolian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
</familyset>
```

Comment: I need to point out that `fromHtml()` is not a `command`. It's a `method`.

Comment: For parsing, through Android 6.0, the `face` attribute on `<font>` is passed straight through to the constructor of `TypefaceSpan`, so whatever `TypefaceSpan` supports is what you can use. For HTML generation from a `Spanned`, it only supports `monospace` mapping to `<tt>`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Actually, since it's not a member of an instance of a class, it's a static function and not a method. I wrote "command" as something more generic, but ok, I changed it to "function".

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there anywhere a list of what I can use there?

Comment: I am not aware of such a list in official documentation. It would be whatever the `Typeface` constructor that takes a `String family` as a parameter supports. From the source code, that's based on reading in some configuration file in `/system/etc/fonts.xml`, at least on Android 6.0, to build up a static map of family name to `Typeface` objects.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK. I opened it, and it has a lot of tags there. Should I use what's for "family" tag, or for "alias" tag? What's "variant"? I've updated the question to hold the XML file content.

Comment: You'd have to rummage through the `Typeface` code for that.

Comment: OK. There, I see only those: "sans-serif" , "serif", "monospace" . Do you think there are variants like roboto-light ?

Comment: if you want custom fonts to be used i think the easiest way is to introduce an own tag (like `<customFont ... />`) and use `Html.TagHandler`

Comment: @pskink But roboto-light isn't customized. it's supposed to be built in...

Comment: but you cannot use it in a built-in `TypefaceSpan` directly afaik

Comment: @pskink But CommonsWare told me to have a look at those files, so you say I shouldn't use anything from there? I don't get what I should be able to use. Please help me and tell me what's allowed.

Comment: try to find out how to use any arbitrary font path with a `TypefaceSpan`, afaik it is not possible: you need to create a custom `TypefaceSpan` class and to use it with `Html#fromHtml` you need a `Html.TagHandler`

Comment: @pskink Again, I don't want to use arbitrary fonts. I want to know which are available out of the box, using the tag I've written about.

Comment: @pskink ok, I think the file did help. I've tested and it works on multiple values shown in the fonts.xml file. Will soon post an example code and screenshot.

Comment: so how do you want to access `roboto-light` font you mentioned for example?

Comment: @pskink As you can see in the code, using "face='sans-serif-light'" is the way to do it. I don't know why, but "roboto" is "sans-serif". Doesn't make much sense to me, but this is how it works.

Comment: @pskink I wonder though, if there are more fonts for WebView, and if what you wrote can provide more fonts to be used.

Comment: unfortunately `Html.TagHandler` does not pass tag's attributes, so you need something like [this](http://pastebin.com/BuPGz1tZ)

Comment: @pskink Thank you. Could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "/system/etc/fonts.xml" file, I've created this code:

```
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Normal <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif'>sans-serif</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif-thin'>sans-serif-thin</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif-light'>sans-serif-light</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif-medium'>sans-serif-medium</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif-black'>sans-serif-black</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif-condensed'>sans-serif-condensed</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif-condensed-light'>sans-serif-condensed-light</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='serif'>serif</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='monospace'>monospace</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='serif-monospace'>serif-monospace</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='casual'>casual</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='cursive'>cursive</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='sans-serif-smallcaps'>sans-serif-smallcaps</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='elegant'>elegant</font> <br/>" +
            "<font face='compact'>compact</font> <br/>"
    ));
```

And here is the result:

[image]

So it seems that all of those are supported, except maybe "elegant" and "compact", which don't seem to be real fonts there (so maybe I didn't understand their purpose).

Also, this was tested on Android 6.0.1 . I wonder how well it works on older versions, which are available there, and if there are new ones in Android N.

Here's the result of running this code on Android 4.0 emulator:

[image]

seems that it doesn't have most of the fonts.

And here is what I see for Xperia J with Android 4.1.2 :

[image]

So here it seems a bit more fonts became available.